# How do I resolve an autowire conflict with NHibernateSagaPersister?

Tags: configuration, nservicebus, saga

I'm trying to wire up my first Saga, and have been unable to get the receiving endpoint to handle start message properly.  I get the following exception:

> SagaMessageHandler Failed handling
>   message.
>   Spring.Objects.Factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating object with name
>   'NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.SagaMessageHandler'
>   : Unsatisfied dependency expressed
>   through object property 'Persister':
>   There are 2 objects of Type
>   [NServiceBus.Saga.ISagaPersister] for
>   autowire by type, when there should
>   have been just 1 to be able to
>   autowire property 'Persister' of
>   object
>   'NServiceBus.Sagas.Impl.SagaMessageHandler'.

I'm guessing that both the in-memory persister and NHibernateSagaPersister are conflicting, but I can't figure out how to resolve this.  My configuration is this:

```
public class SubscriberEndpointConfig : IWantCustomInitialization, IConfigureThisEndpoint
{      
    public void Init()
    {
        _logger.Info("Subscriber is initializing..");

        Configure.With()                 
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport().IsTransactional(true).IsolationLevel(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted).PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus().LoadMessageHandlers(First<GridInterceptingMessageHandler>.Then<SagaMessageHandler>())  
            .Sagas()
            .NHibernateSagaPersister()
            .Log4Net();

    }
}
```

If I remove the LoadMessageHandlers(), the error disappears but of course my handler is never invoked.  Any ideas what's wrong here?  The saga works properly when I am using AsA_Server in the production profile, without the custom initialization, but I need to use that for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nservicebus profiles are configuring the persister for you(http://www.nservicebus.com/Profiles.aspx)

NServiceBus.Lite (default) = InMemory

NServiceBus.Integration = NHibernate + Sqlite

NServiceBus.Production = NHibernate

So in your case you can remove the call to NHibernateSagaPersister() and let the profiles do it's work.

Comment: Even with IWantCustomInitialization?

Comment: So is it true you'd only need the fluent configuration for a non-generic host?  Or under what other circumstances?